# Como bloquear acesso a uma página com htaccess?

Tags: php, htaccess

preciso bloquear o acesso a uma Página (URL), com o htaccess, por exemplo:

http://site_exemplo.com.br/noticias/como-bloquear-acesso-a-pagina

Quero bloquear via htaccess

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?site_exemplo.com.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(noticias/como-bloquear-acesso-a-pagina) - [L,F]
```